# Rails - Oracle gives ORA-03114 error in a certain period of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, oracle-call-interface

guys, I'm running Ruby on rails on my server and oracle for its database. We observed that when we run a query on chron.. it give us ORA-03114 error in a certain point of the query which breaks it. Have you experienced this issue before? May I know your solutions for this. Thank you.

Comment: ORA-03114 is "not connected to ORACLE," or in other words, you lost network connectivity. This problem is likely to have nothing at all to do with Rails. Consult with your network people.

Comment: thanks for that @MarsAtomic

Comment: Specifically, ask your IT crew if there are routers on your intranet that time out after X seconds of inactivity. There's also a possibility that your query can be optimized to a) take less time or b) avoid any delay that leads to network inactivity.